# flake8 e999 on using fstrings in python2 (with future_fstrings)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flake8, pre-commit.com

I'm using fstrings in python2 after `pip install future-fstrings` like the following:

```
# -*- coding: future_fstrings -*-
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        self.__dict__.update(**kw)
        print (f'{self.a}')
        print (f'{self.b}')
        print (f'{self.c}')

A(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

However, when commiting such a file to my project I get:

```
flake8 (Python 3.6 syntax check).....................(no files to check)Skipped
flake8 (Python 2.7)......................................................Failed
hookid: flake8

file_name:0:1: E999 SyntaxError: unknown encoding: future_fstrings
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

`# noqa E999` doesn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pre-commit creates isolated environments for every hook

you'll need to make future-fstrings available to that linter:

```
    -   id: flake8
        additional_dependencies: [future-fstrings]
```

full disclosure: I'm the author of both pre-commit and future-fstrings and the maintainer of flake8, wild when they all overlap heh